# virtualbox gest ip changed

Tags: virtualbox

I'm a novice developer. I am not good at English so I use the translator. I send the file to virtualbox via ftp using filezilla. The ip keeps changing. ex) --> 192.168.xxx -> 08:00:27:8b:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff 1.Why does the tip change? How to set it so that it doesn't change 2. How to transfer ftp using an ip other than 192.168.x.x

Comment: Could you provide more information about the network? Like, which network configuration do you use -- bridged, NAT, host-only?All IP settings in host and guest both?

Comment: (Adter1 - NAT /Adter2 - HOST-ONLY)  (Host Network Manager -Manually setting up the adapter, DHCP CHECK)

Comment: I use kylo-sandbox . this is packege(kylo,nifi,spark,hadoop,mysql...)